# Contact form (PHP and Ajax): how to print data on e-mail?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm new to PHP and I'm having a hard time trying to understand how to print data on e-mail.

I need all data sent to my e-mail, something like this:

Nome: *shows me the name written in the field*

E-mail:  *shows me the e-mail written in the field*

Telefone:  *shows me the phone number written in the field*

Mensagem:  *shows me the message written in the field*

Right now it's only sending me the name and the message, and without the "label" Nome and Mensagem that I need.

How can I achieve this?

Form: http://baskra.com/teste/teste.html

PHP:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

if($_POST)
{
    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        die();
    } 

    $to_Email       = "giovanna.coppola@yahoo.com"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'Formulário de Contato (Site)'; //Subject line for emails

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userPhone"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]))
    {
        die();
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Phone       = filter_var($_POST["userPhone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<6) // If length is less than 6 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Nome muito curto ou campo vazio.');
        exit();
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Insira um e-mail válido.');
        exit();
    }
    if(!is_numeric($user_Phone)) //check entered data is numbers
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Esse campo só aceita números.');
        exit();
    }
    if(strlen($user_Message)<10) //check emtpy message
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Mensagem curta demais.');
        exit();
    }

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "rn" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "rn" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


    @$sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message .'  -'.$user_Name, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Não foi possível enviar. Tente novamente.');
        exit();
    }else{
        echo 'Olá, '.$user_Name.'. Agradecemos o contato! ';
        echo 'Retornaremos o mais breve possível.';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: Change all of your `"rn"` to `"\r\n"`

Comment: Your `header()` calls, you’re using invalid HTTP statuses. The text isn’t for customising (i.e. “Insira um e-mail válido.”) but instead you should be using the appropriate corresponding status for the code. In the case of 500, that’s “Internal Server Error”.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Martin. I'm actually customising a form I've found, and there were custom messages in it, I've just translated them to Portuguese. By the way, what's the correct form of encoding this PHP file to UTF-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$message = 'Nome: '.$user_Name."\r\n".
           'E-mail: '.$user_Email."\r\n".
           'Telefone: '.$user_Phone."\r\n".
           'Mensagem: '.$user_Message;
$sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Please don’t use the error suppression operator (`@`).

Comment: I just copied her code. I don't recommend using it, but it's for the `mail` function -- and the end user doesn't need to see the details of a failed e-mail message. I'd recommend to not output errors and log them instead.